# Spanning/centering elements with Grid/GraphicsGrid when there's a non-equal number of elem. in rows

Tags: legending, grid-layouts, alignment

I'm trying to align elements in `Grid`/`GraphicsGrid`:

`Grid[{{a,b,c},{d,e}}]`

This makes `d,e` aligned to the very left of the bottom row. When I do

`Grid[{{a,b,c},{d,SpanFromLeft,e}}]`

only `d` is in a position where I want it. What to do to have `e` placed just next to `d` (or, in other words, between `b` and `c`)? Unfortunately, there is no `SpanFromRight` (why?).

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I'm in fact interested in `GraphicsGrid`; I thought that `Grid` will be sufficient to convert it, but the plots look terrible (below) or are totally misaligned (when plaing with `ImageSize`, especially when I go to `Grid[{{a,b,c,d},{e,f,g}}]`, where `a,...,g` are `ListContourPlot`s with `Legend`:

[image]

EDIT2: The layout and formatting now seem to be perfect, but... Probably it should now be switched to `Export` problems. I have a nice looking output in MMA, but after `Export` to `.eps` I get this result (placings should be as shown above) (converted to from `.eps` output to `.jpg` 'cause size limit):

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe

```
Column[Row[#, Spacer[5]] & /@ {{a, b, c}, {d, e}},  Alignment -> Center]
```

[image]

```
{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i} = 
  Table[With[{data = MapIndexed[Flatten[{##}] &, RandomReal[1, {100, 2}]], 
     color = RandomChoice[ColorData["Gradients"]], 
     intord = RandomInteger[{0, 4}]}, 
    ListDensityPlot[data, InterpolationOrder -> intord, ColorFunction -> color,
     Mesh -> All, ImageSize -> 200, ImagePadding -> {{20, 5}, {20, 5}}, 
     PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, LegendMarkerSize -> 200]]], {9}];

Column[Row[#, Spacer[5]] & /@ {{a, b, c, d}, {e, f, g}, {h, i}}, Alignment -> Center]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Well, what you want is not really a simple grid, because its irregular, but a combination of two grids:

```
Grid[{{Grid[{{a, b, c}}]}, {Grid[{{d, e}}]}}]
```

The other thing you can try is to construct it by rows and columns:

```
Column[{Row[{a, b, c}, " "], Row[{d, e}, " "]}, Center]
```

Here's nice overview of all this stuff:

> https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/GridsRowsAndColumns.html