# `Export` to `.eps` ruins the formatting of subfigures

Tags: graphics, export, alignment, eps-format

As a result of this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65211/spanning-centering-elements-with-grid-graphicsgrid-when-theres-a-non-equal-numb) an issue of `Export` emerged. I.e., when I set my `.eps` figures with

`plot=Column[Row[#, Spacer[5]] & /@ {{a, b, c, d}, {e, f, g}},  Alignment -> Center]`

it does not look that correct in MMA window (as expected, because the figures are too big for a whole row to fit the screen), but when changed to 50% looks exactly how I want it. So, the placing seem right, so I `Export["plot.eps",plot]`, and them it looks like in the picture below. I guess this has something to do with the fact that `plot` is not a single graphic.

I tried to simply switch `Column/Row` to `GraphicsColumn/GraphicsRow`, but then the alignment is messed (see the question from the link above).

How can I get the correct export?

Thanks in advance![image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you observe is line-wrapping which is turned on in `Column` with the default setting `ItemSize -> Automatic`:

> `ItemSize->Automatic` line-wraps textual elements at the page width

On the same [Documentation page](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ItemSize.html) we read that `ItemSize -> Full`

> allows every item its full width and height

So all what you need is to add `ItemSize -> Full` option into `Column` (stealing [kguler](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/125/kguler)'s code from the [linked thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/65213/280)):

```
{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i} = 
  Table[With[{data = MapIndexed[Flatten[{##}] &, RandomReal[1, {100, 2}]], 
     color = RandomChoice[ColorData["Gradients"]], 
     intord = RandomInteger[{0, 4}]}, 
    ListDensityPlot[data, InterpolationOrder -> intord, ColorFunction -> color,
     Mesh -> All, ImageSize -> 200, ImagePadding -> {{20, 5}, {20, 5}}, 
     PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, LegendMarkerSize -> 200]]], {9}];

plots = Column[Row[#] & /@ {{a, b, c, d}, {e, f, g}, {h, i}}, 
  Alignment -> Center, ItemSize -> Full];    

Export["plots.pdf", plots]
```

Here is how it looks in Adobe Acrobat:

[image: screenshot]

The same effect can be achieved by replacing `Row` with `Grid` which does not allow line-wrapping:

```
plots = Column[Grid[{#}] & /@ {{a, b, c, d}, {e, f, g}, {h, i}}, Alignment -> Center]
```