# GraphicsGrid of plots with legends

Tags: graphics, bugs, legending, grid-layouts

I use `GraphicsGrid` to get a table of contour plots, where each of the plots is using its own scaling, so I want to include the bar legend for each of the plots. But if I do this, `GraphicsGrid` seems to ignore the place needed for the legend when calculating the grid item size, and the plots are scaled larger then grid cells.

MWE:

```
GraphicsGrid@
 Table[ContourPlot[ Cos[x]/k + Cos[ m y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}, 
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic], {k, 1, 
   2}, {m, 1, 2}]
```

[image: oversized items in GrpahicsGrid]

Is there any better way to fix it rather then to set fixed plot size and to tune manually the `ItemAspectRatio`, like below?

```
GraphicsGrid[
 Table[ContourPlot[ Cos[x]/k + Cos[ m y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}, 
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
   ImageSize -> 100], {k, 1, 2}, {m, 1, 2}], ItemAspectRatio -> .6]
```

[image]

Comment: This is a known bug. I have added the tag 'bugs'.

Comment: [Related](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65211/spanning-centering-elements-with-grid-graphicsgrid-when-theres-a-non-equal-numb); maybe a dupe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug. I had a similar problem with `GraphicsGrid`, reported it, and received a reply from WRI tech support. I quote the relevant portion.

> When you put the plots inside a GraphicsGrid, they are put inside individual insets. Unfortunately, there is a known issue with GraphicsGrid failing to determine the optimal size for graphics with insets.
>
> So, I recommend you to avoid using plots along the GraphicsGrid.

Try `Grid` instead.

```
Grid @
  Table[
    ContourPlot[Cos[x]/k + Cos[m y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}, 
      ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic],
    {k, 1, 2}, {m, 1, 2}]
```

[image: grid]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I would still prefer to use manual tuning because of not uniform heights of the bar legends with `Grid` method.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to rasterize the plots before using `GraphicsGrid`

```
GraphicsGrid[
 Table[Rasterize[
   ContourPlot[Cos[x]/k + Cos[m y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}, 
    ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
    ImageSize -> 300]], {k, 1, 2}, {m, 1, 2}]]
```

this will produce 
[image]