# Spanning horizontally and vertically in Grid

Tags: grid-layouts, alignment, spacing

I'm trying to make a `Grid` that has one cell that spans horizontally and one that spans vertically, like so (generated manually with `Graphics`):

[image]

But when I try to do this with Grid, the right-most vertical cell doesn't span both rows:

```
Grid[{
    { Style["1", FontSize->30], SpanFromLeft, Style["4\n4", FontSize->30] },
    { Style["2", FontSize->30], Style["3", FontSize->30], SpanFromAbove }
}, Frame->All, Spacings->{3,3} ]
```

[image]

Since I have the frame active, I know the right-most cell does in fact span both rows, as we see if we remove `SpanFromAbove`:

```
Grid[{
    { Style["1", FontSize->30], SpanFromLeft, Style["4\n4", FontSize->30] },
    { Style["2", FontSize->30], Style["3", FontSize->30] }
}, Frame->All, Spacings->{3,3} ]
```

[image]

Is it not possible to combine vertical and horizontal spans in a grid? Is there a better function, like some combination of `Column` and `Row`? Thx

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean, is the height of the first item the problem? Because except that size issue everything seems ok, with `Alignment -> {Center, Center}` you can see that the item with 4s is streched. Or did I miss the point? `Grid[{{Style["1", FontSize -> 30], SpanFromLeft, 
   Style["4\n4", FontSize -> 30]}, {Style["2", FontSize -> 30], 
   Style["3", FontSize -> 30], SpanFromAbove}}, Frame -> All, 
 Spacings -> {3, 3}, Alignment -> {Center, Center}]`

Comment: Even with the alignment, the content of the right-most box never stretches to the second row. Here's the same thing with four "4"s: `Grid[{{Style["1", FontSize -> 30], SpanFromLeft, Style["4\n4\n4\n4\n", FontSize -> 30]}, {Style["2", FontSize -> 30], Style["3", FontSize -> 30], SpanFromAbove}}, Frame -> All, Spacings -> {3, 3}, Alignment -> {Center, Center}]`

Comment: FWIW, this works fine if you replace `Grid` with `GraphicsGrid`. Seems like a bug to me.

Comment: [This is what I see - link.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSBaP.png) But I wouldn't be surprised by another bug of Grid, just want to make sure it is clear.

Comment: It is a bug, but this description doesn't quite characterize it correctly. The problem isn't that a vertical spanning member can't properly span.  Changing `Alignment` shows this. @ChrisWilson misses seeing this in part because of an extra newline at the end...try wrapping `Framed` around the `Style` or using `Bottom` alignment.  What it cannot do is to calculate the required height of the first row correctly.  It apportions to the first row enough pixels to hold everything, although it could have subtracted the number of vertical pixels in the second row.

Comment: Well said! Should we submit a bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I encountered a similar problem, and I found this [idea](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/65217) that uses Grid inside Grid.

```
Grid[{
  {Grid[{
     {Style["1", FontSize -> 30], SpanFromLeft},
     {Style["2", FontSize -> 30], Style["3", FontSize -> 30]}
     }, Frame -> All, Spacings -> {3, 3}],
   Grid[{
     {Style["4", FontSize -> 30]},
     {Style["4", FontSize -> 30]}
     }, Frame -> True, Spacings -> {3, 2.99}]}
  }, Spacings -> -0.1]
```

I played with the Spacings a bit, to make the graph aligned, and here is the result.

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! (Though I wish it wasn't necessary...)