# How to arrange images in a hierarchical structure?

Tags: image, grid-layouts

Something like this picture

[image]

I've tried to use [`ImageCollage`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageCollage.html) with different weights and other conditions, but all of them arrange pictures arbitrarily. For instance

```
ImageCollage[{4 -> im0, 1 -> im1, 1 -> im2},  Background -> None]
```

organize the images horizontally:

[image]

and so on.

Comment: closely related / possible duplicate : [Spanning/centering elements with Grid/GraphicsGrid when there's a non-equal number of elem. in rows](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/65211/125)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Module[{pl, w = 500, h = 100},
 pl[frac_] := Framed[
   BarChart[
    RandomReal[1, 5]
    , AspectRatio -> frac h/w
    , PlotTheme -> "Scientific"
    , ImageSize -> 0.9 {w/frac, h}
    ], ImageSize -> {w/frac, h}];
 GraphicsGrid[
  {
   PadRight[{pl[1]}, 4, SpanFromLeft],
   {pl[2], SpanFromLeft, pl[2], SpanFromLeft},
   {pl[4], pl[4], pl[4], pl[4]}
   }
  , ImageSize -> {w, 4 h}
  , Spacings -> {0, 0}
  ]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 6):

```
    SeedRandom@2;
    p = Table[BarChart[RandomReal[1, 5]], 7];

Grid[{{p[[1]], SpanFromLeft}, {p[[2]], SpanFromLeft, p[[3]], 
   SpanFromLeft}, Join @@ {p[[4 ;; 7]]}}, Frame -> All, 
 Alignment -> Center]
```

[image]